# AngularJS: variable in ng-repeat without $scope is in its local scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, angularjs, coffeescript

here is the code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="{'red': click}">
    <span ng-click="click = !click">{{i}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="j in items" ng-class="{'red': f_click}">
    <span ng-click="fun_click($index)">{{j}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`f_click` change in `fun_click` function.

```
$scope.fun_click = (idx) ->
    $scope.f_click = !$scope.f_click
```

the complete codes:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Zmoqbv?p=preview

I wonder that the variable `click` in the first list is a local  variable for each ng-repeat element ?
how was it work ?

How could I make the `f_click` in the second list works like the `click` ?
Seems the `$scope.f_click` is the only one variable in the ng-controller.

---

Updated:

I think I just did things wrong.
I should not write things in "View".

read-only in View;
write-only in Controller.
http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/07/angularjs-best-practices.html

Comment: thank you guys! I read all your answers, and I learn a lot! thank you all so much! I hope I could help somebody in somedays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I make the f_click in the second list works like the click

As I know you can't. From your 1st example `click` doesn't refer to any scope.

`f_click` refers to specific scope and any change distributes on all elements (aka on all items in your loop)

You can provide flag per value like:

```
$scope.items2 = [
{'name': 'Google','value':false},
{'name': 'Apple','value':false},
{'name': 'Yahoo','value':false},
{'name': 'IBM','value':false},
];

 $scope.fun_click = (item) ->
   item.value = !item.value;
```

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="j in items2" ng-class="{'red': j.value}">
    <span ng-click="fun_click(j)">{{j.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5ZAsU?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: you even don't need to give them default `value: false` , you know: http://plnkr.co/edit/qgXbDp?p=preview

Comment: @Cherniv You are right 100% but it makes code readable. After 2 month other programmer need to spend time to understand why it false,. Its like in Java you type `if(flag)` or `if(flag==true)`

Answer (score 3):

`ng-repeat` creates a scope for each iteration. The `click` variable lives inside each `ng-repeat` scope, in other words it is private to that. If you place `{{click}}` just after the `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">` but before the `ng-repeat`, it will show nothing because `click` exists in the inner scope(s).

On the other hand `f_click` lives in the scope of the `MainCtrl`, which is the *parent* scope for both `ng-repeat`s. The function that changes it (`fun_click`) lives in the parent scope too. The `ng-repeat` scopes *inherit the single instance* of this variable, thus the observed behaviour.

To make `f_click` work as `click` you would have to make it private to the scope of each `ng-repeat` iteration. One solution is to define `f_click` and `fun_click()` in a controller *inside* `ng-repeat`. Other solutions are possible.

Comment: "ng-repeat creates a scope for each iteration." thanks! @Nikos I will read the docs more deeply.

Answer (score 3):

The reason first ngRepeat works and the second one doesn't is because ngRepeat create a scope for each item.  In other words, there is a instances of `click` variable for each item in `items` and by toggling the `click` variable inside a ngClick you are in effect working with the private instance.  In the second example, you access the `f_click` using `$scope` of the controller, which is the parent of ngRepeat scope, and therefore changes are propagated to all children scopes.

A simple solution to your problem is therefore pass the `f_click` instance created in ngRepeat to your function:

```
// Script
$scope.fun_click = (toggle) ->
    return !toggle

// HTML
<span ng-click="f_click=fun_click(f_click)">{{j}}</span>
```

If you wish to maintain the state in `$scope`, you can use a dictionary to track the status of each  `$index`:

```
// Script
$scope.form_status = {}
$scope.fun_click = (index) ->
    $scope.form_status[index] = !$scope.form_status[index]

// HTML
<li ng-repeat="j in items" ng-class="{'red': form_status[$index]}">
    <span ng-click="fun_click($index)">{{j}}</span>
</li>
```

Here is updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/w6RLed?p=preview